# How to use c# get and set methods in Java.

Tags: java, accessor

I'm trying to convert some c# code to java and I'm having a little difficulty.

I have the following code and I want to know how to implement the CurrentState line in Java.

```
public class StateMachine
{
    **public static State CurrentState { get; set; }**
    public enum State
    {
        Init,
        Data,
        Text,
        Close,
        Invalid
    }
}
```

This is my meager attempt to resolve the issue, but it isn't quite right.

```
    static State currentState;

public static void setCurrentState(State currentState)
{
    this.currentState = currentState;
}

public static State getCurrentState()
{
    return currentState;
}
```

Question has now been answered and here is the correct working code in case anyone wants to see it.

```
public static State currentState;

public static State getCurrentState()
{
    return currentState;
}

public static void setCurrentState(State newState)
{
    currentState = newState;
}
```

Using these getCurrentState and setCurrentState methods I can now easily implement this in a case statement which was the original goal.

Comment: What sort of errors, in what line?

Comment: What specific errors do you get?

Comment: It says state cannot be resolved or is not a field, state cannot be resolved to a variable. It also giving me a syntax error on setting Init = 0x00 for some reason.

Comment: @HighCore Constructive comments generally would help the OP and future users get their task done as they need.

Comment: I can add static to the getState and SetState functions but it still doesn't resolve my error. Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough, I want to what to do to the StateMachine class so that I can utilize it in the switch statement to get and set the states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the basic question, you need to declare a backing field called `state` for the get and set.

```
public class StateMachine {

    // This is the missing part
    private static State state;

    public static State getState() {
       return state;
    }

    public static void setState(State newState) {
        state = newState;
    }
}
```

Comment: these class members should be `static` to match the OP's C# version.

Comment: @HighCore agreed.. let me edit the answer.

Comment: I was just finding this solution kinda. This is what I have           static State currentState;
 
 public static void setCurrentState(State currentState)
 {
  this.currentState = currentState;
 }
 
 public static State getCurrentState()
 {
  return currentState;
 } However it really doesn't like using this.currentState with static.

Comment: My bad.. see the corrected answer.. all you need is a different variable name.

Comment: Ah ok that fixed it and I updated my question to be more clear as well. Do I need to declare the value of Init outside of enum to get my syntax error to away for that?

Comment: You don't need the Init value. It is set to 0 by default, which matches the original version. Just remove the `= 0x00` part or change it to `= 0`.

Comment: Awesome, I'm going to mark this as answered. You've been very helpful.